# Unable to create nomedia file

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

Through Android SDK and AVD Manager I have created an AVD of android3.0 version with size option as 1024MiB. In my application class I have asked to create a directory so that I can cache images. But I get error over there as

```
09-07 15:32:31.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create nomedia file.
```

My code is:

```
File baseDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myapp");
File storageDirectory = new File(baseDirectory, "imagecache");
File nomediaFile = new File(storageDirectory, NOMEDIA);
nomediaFile.createNewFile();
```

Error comes over in the 4th line. Could anyone please help me out. I am new to honeycomb. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try storageDirectory.mkdirs(); and check if it works

Comment: i gave that line too...but if I give a check isExists() after that its still returning false.

Comment: Are you sure its mkdirs() not mkdir() and also use the log to print the path of  baseDirectory and what is NOMEDIA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have suggested, you should have `mkdirs()` to ensure your directory path is there. You also need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.